# Async if is skipped and function jumps to end

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I have this async function:

```
private async Task<bool> ShowAboutToMatchAlert()
{
    bool res = true;

    if(Preferences.Get("WantSeeFirstMatchAlertAgain", true))
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("...");

            if (answer)
            {
                Preferences.Set("WantSeeFirstMatchAlertAgain", false);
                res = true;
            }
            else
            {
                res = false;
            }
        });
    }

    return res; 
}
```

What happens is this functions shows an alert. As soon as the user picks an option (yes or no) the `if(answer)` is fired and depending on the input, the result is given.

However, the whole function does not **wait** for the result and immediately skips forward to the final return. So always `true` is being returned (as the function is async).

The function itself **has** to be async in order for it to be awaited since this function is also called from another async function.

How can I make this function `await` the `if` part and not just skip forward?

Simplest solution of course would be to make this function be not async but then I cannot return "true" or "false" anymore but have to return `System.Threading.Task.Task<bool>`. So that is not an option.

Comment: I think this call should be awaited: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: What type is your `Device` variable? If it is your own type, can you show what `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` does?

Comment: Device is from XAMARIN.FORMS. It is a crossplattform app. The alert HAS to be invoked on main thread.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread is returning void. how would I wait for this?

Comment: Try using `await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync( ... )`

Comment: Alternatively, you can wrap entire method inside `BeginIvoke...` method call.

Comment: ^^ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.invokeonmainthreadasync?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Is this an _XY_ problem? Why does `DisplayAlert` need to be `async`?  If it's just a modal popup dialog surely it should be synchonous?

Comment: Because you are returning `res` you need to `await Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.  Norrmally it is fine to have _fire-and-forget_ `Tasks` but not when the method depends on the result

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i cant wait for void and i cannot wrap the whole method because at least the final return needs to be outside of the braces. therfore nothing is awaited in this function.

Comment: @MickyD since i need to wait for the user input here, i have to await the alert being closed to work with the result (ANSWER). I cannot await Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread because it returns void

Comment: you don´t need `await` to wait for a modal dialog. The point of a modal dialog is that execution only continues when there was some user-action.

Comment: @HimBromBeere without the await, it says cannot convert system.threading.tasks.task into bool

Comment: then please show your `DisplayAlert`-method. I doubt it should be `async` in the first place.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it is coming from xamarin.forms. i just followed the docs here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149889/is-it-possible-to-wait-for-device-begininvokeonmainthread-code-to-finish

Comment: inno the [`Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.invokeonmainthreadasync) method suggested by MichałTurczyn does not return `void`. It returns a `Task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` returns void and cannot be awaited - you can use `TaskCompletionSource` to achieve your goal. This class allows you to obtain `Task` (which can be awaited) and manually set it's completion with result. Your code then becomes:

```
private Task<bool> ShowAboutToMatchAlert()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    if(Preferences.Get("WantSeeFirstMatchAlertAgain", true))
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("...");

            if (answer)
            {
                Preferences.Set("WantSeeFirstMatchAlertAgain", false);
                // signal completion with "true" result
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                // signal completion with "false" result
                tcs.SetResult(false);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        tcs.SetResult(false);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Beware that `tcs.SetResult` (or `SetCancelled` or `SetException`) should be called on *all* code paths, including exceptions, for example potentially produced by `DisplayAlert` (not shown in the above example), otherwise you can get into nasty deadlocks.